# The existence of a polynomial factor

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

Given two polynomials $p_1(x_1,\dots, x_m)$ and $p_2(x_1,\dots, x_n)$ over reals, where $m > n$, and we know that $p_2(x_1,\dots, x_n)=0 \implies p_1(x_1,\dots, x_m) =0$.

My question is:

> Under what conditions there exists a polynomial $Q(x_1, \dots, x_m)$ such that
>   $$p_1(x_1,\dots, x_m) = Q(x_1, \dots, x_m) p_2(x_1,\dots, x_n)\ ?$$

Comment: The condition is very unclear. If $p_2$ is given, either it is zero or not. If $p_2$ is not the zero polynomial, the condition is true for *any* $p_1$.

Comment: I think the condition is $p_2(a_1,\dots, a_n)=0 \implies p_1(a_1,\dots, a_m) =0$ for $(a_1,\dots, a_n)  \in \mathbb R^n$. In words: whenever $p_2$ is zero at a point, $p_1$ is zero for the whole fiber over that point, the fiber being with respect to the canonical projection $\mathbb R^m \to \mathbb R^n$.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! You might want to include your own thoughts here: this helps other people to give answers on the right level.

Answer (score 1):

Not true in general.

Take $p_2(x)=x^2+1$ and $p_1(x,y)=x^2-y+1$.

Then $p_2(a)=0 \implies p_1(a,b)=0$ vacuously, because $p_2$ has no real zeros, but $p_2$ does not divide $p_1$.

Here are some other examples:

- $p_2(x)=x(x^2+1), p_1(x,y)=x$
- $p_2(x)=x^2, p_1(x,y)=x$
  (this one works even over $\mathbb C$ and is a general result, Hilbert's Nullstellensatz)
- $p_2(x,y)=x^2+y^2, p_1(x,y,z)=x$

Comment: The condition p2(a)=0⟹p1(a,b)=0 is true for the above polynomials only for the case b=0.

Comment: @lhf do you have an example when $p_2$ has a zero?

Comment: I see, you are right.

Comment: @Qidi, see my edited answer.

Comment: Thanks, for your counterexample. It has been useful.